# What is the experience required to advance in each level in Payday 2?

Tags: payday-2

I know it requires more experience to reach the next level with every level gained.  For instance, going from level 1-10 is much easier than going from level 50-60.  What is the exact formula for the amount of experience required to advance in each level in Payday 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging in the PayDay 2 wikia, I've found a table detailing experience required for all levels from 0 to 100. [The table can be found here](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Reputation_%28Payday_2%29#Experience_table) (click the 'show' link to make it visible).

Comment: You have to click the 'show' link next to Level. I'd copy and paste the table into your answer to make it handier for people.

Comment: at level 85 you are 50% the way through levelling up to the next level of infamy, if i recall correctly